# Create a subdomain?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, subdomain

In some website i found that is it possible for me to programmatically create a subdomain to the website i own from C# WinForm application.

How can I create a subdomain on my website, given the server host, user and pass?

Comment: AppDomains have _nothing_ to do with domain names.  You need to configure IIS and DNS.

Comment: "*In some website i found that is it possible for me to programmatically create a subdomain to the website i own from C# WinForm application.*" So you have the solution?

Comment: No, @SteveB they say that i need to use  AppDomain.CreateDomain but according to SLaks, AppDomains it have nothing to do with domain name

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a program to edit DNS records for a company with 30,000 domains and I used WMI to edit the records.

Your starting place is the [DNS WMI Provider Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [this article on editing DNS with WMI](http://www.indented.co.uk/index.php/2008/10/23/modifying-dns-records-with-wmi/).

You can use WMI in a .NET application - although many samples out there are for Powershell etc.